# send logs of flask through rsyslog on remote server

Tags: linux, rsyslog

I have flask running in my environment which creates logs in /var/log/api/api.log. i have configured rsyslog service to send all logs to my remote server but rsyslog sending api.logs to syslog file  on remote server. i have also tried by creating configuration file in ryslog.d/api.conf but no success.
**my rsyslog.d/api.conf file on client server**

```
$ModLoad imfile

$InputFileName  /var/log/api/api.log
$InputFileTag   api
$InputFileStateFile     api
$InputFileSeverity      info
$InputFileFacility      local7
$InputRunFileMonitor
$InputFilePersistStateInterval 1000
local7.*  @@myIP:514
```

**MY rsyslog.conf file**

```
#  /etc/rsyslog.conf    Configuration file for rsyslog.
#
#                       For more information see
#                       /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/rsyslog_conf.html


*.* @@MYIP:514



module(load="imuxsock") # provides support for local system logging
module(load="imklog")   # provides kernel logging support
#module(load="immark")  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# provides UDP syslog reception
#module(load="imudp")
#input(type="imudp" port="514")

# provides TCP syslog reception
#module(load="imtcp")
#input(type="imtcp" port="514")


#
# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
#
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

#
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileOwner root
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022

#
# Where to place spool and state files
#
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

#
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
#
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf


#
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
#
auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
#cron.*                         /var/log/cron.log
daemon.*                        -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.*                           -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log
user.*                          -/var/log/user.log
api.*                           -/var/log/api/api.log
#
# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
#
mail.info                       -/var/log/mail.info
mail.warn                       -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err                        /var/log/mail.err

#
# Some "catch-all" log files.
#
*.=debug;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        news.none;mail.none     -/var/log/debug
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        cron,daemon.none;\
        mail,news.none          -/var/log/messages

#
#
*.emerg                         :omusrmsg:*
```

Comment: Provide relevant information such as config files which will enable an answer.

Comment: @tater i have added my configuration files of  client server.